# C# Hides Inherited Member

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have this setup and get a compiler warning "... hides inherited member ...".  How do I fix?

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
}

public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

}

public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product>
{
    // Product specific interface code here
}

public class ProductRepository : EFRepository<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    public ProductRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) { }

    public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.Include("Table1").Include("Table2").AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

I get the compiler warning message but when running application, I get a `StackOverflowException` error.  Adding the new keyword still generates the `StackOverflowException` error. Override keyword doesn't work. If I comment out the `ProductRepository` `GetAll()` method, all is fine and dandy.  But I need to override the `GetAll()` method.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "override keyword doesn't work"?

Comment: I think you need the `new` keyword, not override.

Comment: If you are marking GetAll() as virtual in the base class and then overriding it in a child class with the override keyword, then the method overriding should work.  What do you mean, it "doesn't work"? Details?  Also can you give more info on your exception being thrown?

Comment: The code is executed from a Self Host Web Api so I get a general StackOverflowException error with both the new keyword and override keyword used in the ProductRepository  If you notice, a virtual GetAll() is defined in the IRepository interface as well as in the EFRepository class.  I think the code is barking not know which GetAll() to override?

Comment: well, with the way you have things setup I can guarantee that you need to be using the override keyword on the GetAll function in your child class.  There is something else that is causing the stack overflow exception.  check the rest of your code for infinite loops.

Comment: The override keyword works.  The actual problem has to do with this line - return DbSet.Include("Table1").Include("Table2").AsQueryable(); It doesn't like the .Include() stuff.  return DbSet; works. I need to bring back the related entities.  This is now an EF issue.

Comment: What is the full text of the error message? What method is being hidden?

Comment: Thank you guys for taking the time trying to help me out. The issue ended up having to do with Newton's JSON.Net serialization.  I had to make a configuration setting with ReferenceLoopHandling and set it to Ignore.  The StackOverflowException was traced down to being a Object graph for type '' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Mark ProductRepository.GetAll with the "new" keyword:

```
public new IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
{
    return DbSet.Include("Table1").Include("Table2").AsQueryable();
}
```

This will hide the method EFRepository.GetAll().

You can also choose to override the base method, if you want both methods to return the same result:

```
public override IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
{
    return DbSet.Include("Table1").Include("Table2").AsQueryable();
}
```